# Map containing itself as a value;

Tags: java, dictionary, equals, hashcode

Directly from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) java doc:

> A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a
>   map to contain itself as a key. While it is permissible for a map to
>   contain itself as a value, extreme caution is advised: the equals and
>   hashCode methods are no longer well defined on such a map.

Why would the hashcode and equals no longer be well defined on such a map?

Comment: if i remember correctly the equals method checks if the contents of the maps are equal. and this is done using the equals method of the contents i.e. the map itself. I'm pretty sure we end up with a StackOverflowError

Comment: Might be the way a maps equals function looks? maybe it'll cause an infinite loop? Just a thought

Comment: @MarcoForberg If I remember correctly it's best practice to check if the object that you're comparing against is actually yourself and return true immediately if so.

Comment: @NamSan Create two maps (lets say A and B) and put A into B and B into A. now try A.equals(B). You will get the expected behaviour and checking reference equality does not help here, but btw. whenever I implement `equals()` I do exactly as you say ;)

Comment: @MarcoForberg In your example it would end up producing a StackOverflowError, but in the example given in the question it would not produce a StackOverflowError

Comment: @NamSan true finally had the time to check it and you're right. if you insert a map into itself, `equals()` will still work, but `hashcode()` will fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full quote of the paragraph from the Java Docs is:

> Note: **great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map.** A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a map to contain itself as a key. While it is permissible for a map to contain itself as a value, extreme caution is advised: the equals and hashCode methods are no longer well defined on such a map.

The AbstractMap.hashCode() method uses the hash code of the key value pairs in the map to compute a hash code. Therefore the hash code generated from this method would change every time the map is modified.

The hash code is used to compute the bucket to place a new entry. If the map was used as a key within itself then the computed bucket would be different everytime a new entry is updated/removed/modified. Therefore, future lookups with the map as a key will most likely fail because a differnt bucket is computed from the hash code. Future puts may not be able to detect that the key is already present in the map and then allow multiple entries that have the same key (but in different buckets)

Answer (score 5):

The relevant part form AbstractMap.equals which is used by most Map implementations:

```
            Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                Entry<K,V> e = i.next();
                K key = e.getKey();
                V value = e.getValue();
                if (value == null) {
                    if (!(m.get(key)==null && m.containsKey(key)))
                        return false;
                } else {
                    if (!value.equals(m.get(key))) // would call equals on itself.
                        return false;
                }
            }
```

Adding the map as a value would result in an infinite loop.

Comment: The first statement in the equals() method is **if (o == this) return true;** I think this would prevent the infinate loop, since it would return immediately and never execute the code that you've highlighted.

Comment: Damn you are right. Answer needs to be unmarked. Maybe it is because it's so implementation dependend that they didn't define it not recommend it.

Comment: well you can create a problem by creating two maps, put one map into the other and invoke equals on one map with the other as parameter. or you simply put one map into itself and call hashcode()

Answer (score 1):

Two maps are equal if the same keys map om the same values. (In some implementations.) So to check equality, the equality of every member should be checked.

Therefore, if a map contains itself, you would get an infinite recurssion of equality checks.

The same goes for hashes, as these can be calculated dependend on the hashes of the elements in the map.

Example:

```
Map<Int, Object> ma;
Map<Int, Object> mb;
Map<Int, Object> mc;

ma.put(1, ma);
ma.put(2, mb);
mc.put(1, ma);
mc.put(2, mb);
```

As a human, we can see `ma` and `mc` are equal from the definition. A computer would see 2 maps on mb (an empty map) in both maps, which is good.  It would see 1 maps on another map in both mc and ma. It checks if these maps are equal. To determine this, it checks again if the two value for 1 are equals. And again.

Note that this is not the case for all implementations. Some implementations might check equality on the location in memory the object is saved, ... But every recursive check will loop infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

To try to explain it:

The equals method will iterate over both Maps and call the equals method of each key and value of the map. So, if a map contains itself, you would keep calling the equals method indefinitely.

The same thing happens with the hash code.

Source: source code of the class AbstractMap